# Export to xls using php

Tags: php, csv, export

I want to lock the first three columns: Student id , School id, and Student Name, so that, the respective teacher can add only marks obtained  in the exported file. How can I do that?

```
 public function actionStddetails(){
    $api = new ApiRequest();
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $url = '/api/student/viewstudent';
    $payload = "{'subject_id':'245','esd_id':'2','class_id':'5','qfe_id':'1','exam_id':'3','ref_id':'1','wac':'2','school_id':'2'}";
    $url = '/api/examscore/studentlist';
    $result = $api->request($url, $payload);
    $stddtls = $result->Table1;
    $csv_header='';
    $csv_header .= 'Student id,'.'School id,'.'Student Name,'.'Marks Obtained,'."\n";
    // loop over the rows, outputting them
    $csv_row ='';
    foreach ($stddtls as $stddtl){
        $csv_row .= '"' . $stddtl->stud_id . '",'.'"' . $stddtl->school_id . '",'.'"' . $stddtl->stud_name. '",'."\n";
    }
    /* Download as CSV File */
    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=toy_csv.csv');
    echo $csv_header . $csv_row;

}
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: I want to lock First three columns ie Student id ,School id, Student Name.So that the respective teacher can add only Marks obtained in exported file? ie can only read those column but cannot write in it.
By the way qsn was clear

Comment: So you want the donwloaded csv to have write-protection for several parts?

Comment: yes first three columns

Comment: It is not possible to do this with a CSV file, as it is just plain text - nothing more, nothing less. If you want to have write protection for specific fields, you have to us another method. You could e.g. create a web-interface where only the value for the mark can be changed and the other values are only displayed, but not modifiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked  with this.But with xls document

```
public function actionStddetails(){
    $api = new ApiRequest();
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $url = '/api/student/viewstudent';
    $payload = "{'subject_id':'245','esd_id':'2','class_id':'5',
   'qfe_id':'1','exam_id':'3','ref_id':'1',
   'wac':'2','school_id':'2'}";
    $url = '/api/examscore/studentlist';
    $result = $api->request($url, $payload);
    $stddtls = $result->Table1;
    //var_dump($stddtls);exit;
    try {
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        // Initialise the Excel row number
        $rowCount = 1;
        //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields

        $column = 'A';
        $result = ['Student id','School id','Student Name','Marks 
        Obtained'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
        {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$rowCount, 
          $result[$i]);
            $column++;
        }
        $rowCount = 2;
        //$column = 'A';
        foreach ($stddtls as $stddtl)
        {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$rowCount, 
                          $stddtl->stud_id);
             $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 
                          $stddtl->school_id);
             $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, 
                          $stddtl->stud_name);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, 
                           "");
             $rowCount++;
        }
        $count = count($stddtls)+1;
        $objSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        $objSheet->getProtection()->setPassword('hello');
        $objSheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
        $objSheet->getStyle('D1:D'.$count)->getProtection()-
         >setLocked(\PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
        $objSheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
        // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="results.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 
                    'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        }
        catch(\yii\base\Exception $e){
         var_dump($e);
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with a CSV file, as it is just plain text - nothing more, nothing less. If you want to have write protection for specific fields, you have to use another method.

You could e.g. create a web-interface where only the value for the mark can be changed and the other values are only displayed, but not modifiable.